# What does a mode mean in the context of Quantum Transmitting Boundary Method (QTBM)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, simulations, quantum-transport

The problem statement in the [original paper](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jap/article/67/10/6353/502152/The-quantum-transmitting-boundary-method) by C.S.Lent and D.J.Kirkner says:

> *Given*: The total energy E, the potential energy in each region, $V_{i}(x,y)$, $i=0,1,2,...,n$, and the complex amplitudes of each **incoming mode** in each lead....

What exactly is a mode? How is it different from the wavefunction?

Comment: In general a mode would be a solution to the Schrodinger equation that satisfies a boundary condition. While many wave functions might solve the Schrodinger equation, boundary conditions often lead to discrete solutions. E.G. an integral number of wavelengths must fit in a box.